# Admin User Role Unable to See Private Posts

Tags: user-roles

I have set a few posts to Private. When I login with Admin role I'd expect to still see the posts but they do not appear in the blog list. Changing the posts back to public and they appear.

As Admin my capability seems to include 'read_private_posts'. So I'm not sure why I can't see the posts.

Comment: Are they Posts as in WP Core Posts, or a custom post type?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the blog list" - where are they not appearing? in wp-admin or somewhere on the front end? You may have a theme that only lists publicly published items.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back. From looking at the posts table in the db it looks like Post Type = Post. Also, I just meant that they were not appearing on the main blog page on the front end. The page that displays all the blogs when they are published. I'll need to check on the theme point to see if it is only displaying public posts.